# array_key_exists():the first argument should be either a string or an integer while uploading files

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I send data using ajax jQuery I can see that files are moved to server but can't be uploaded.
Here's my code for php store function:

```php
public function store(VehiculeStoreRequest $request)
{
    dd($request["document"]);
    //  dd($request["document"]);
    // getting validated fields
    $validated = $request->validated();
    // uploading vehicule image
    $file = $validated["image"];
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());
    $path = "public/";
    Storage::disk('local')->put($path . $filename, file_get_contents($file));
    $validated['image'] = $filename;
    $validated['disponibilite'] = true;
             
    $vehic = Vehicule::create([
        "matricule" => $request["matricule"],
        "marque" => $request["marque"],
        "model" => $request["model"],
        "nom" => $request["nom"],
        "prenom" => $request["prenom"],
        "login" => $request["login"],
        "ps" => $request["password"],
        "num_agrement" => $request["num_agrement"],
        "image" => $filename,
        "type_vehicule_id" => $request["type_vehicule_id"],
        "ville_id" => $request["ville_id"]
    ]);
    
    $request->validate([
        'document.*' => 'mimes:csv,txt,xlx,xls,png,jpg,docx,zip,rar,sql,php,js,txt,cmd,mp4,mp3,pdf' 
    ]); 
    // if ($request->hasfile('document'))
    if ($request->hasFile($request["document"])) {
        foreach ($request->file('document') as $key => $file) {
            $path = "public/";
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::disk('local')->put($path . $name, file_get_contents($file));
            $insert[$key]['name'] = $name;
            $insert[$key]['store_path'] = $path;
            document_vehicule::create([
                "nom" => $name,
                "vehicule_id" => $vehic->id
            ]);
        }
    }
```

also the jQuery code:

```js
// upload multiple file (error)
var filesLength = document.getElementById('document').files.length;
for (var i=0; i<filesLength; i++) {
    form_data.append("document[]", document.getElementById('document').files[i])
}
```

Comment: what is this supposed to be checking? `if($request->hasFile($request["document"]))` ... `$request['document']` would be the actual file or files, no?

Comment: The correct way to use `hasFile()` method is this: `$request->hasFile('document')`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files